# Reference book/ Notes/ articles for p rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, cryptography, class-field-theory

I am a graduate student. I want to learn about $p$-rank and $p$-torsion points on curves over finite fields. As the base, I have read Stictenoth's book  ''Algebraic Function Fields and Codes'' but he did not discuss much about the $p$ rank of curves. Is there any book/notes that discuss the theory of $p$ ranks of curves (possibly over an algebraically closed field or over characteristic 0 fields but containing some chapters on what will happen in positive characteristic)?

Comment: If you're a graduate student, you should ask your advisor or other members of your department in addition to asking here- they'll know you better, and you may strike up some good working relationships.

Comment: I have heard of $p$-torsion points on elliptic curves (where there is an addition operation of points), but what does $p$-torsion mean on general curves? Do you go to the Jacobian? If so, then you should pick up a book on abelian varieties. Unfortunately (for me) that theory runs a bit deeper than I can handle. You see, I have only read Stichtenoth (and Silverman's book on elliptic curves).

Comment: @ Kreiser. Thanks for your suggestion. He said to read some of the articles related to these, but I thought to read some books or note before diving into it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes! by p torsion I meant to go to the Jacobian. Thank you for your comments. I think I should look into Silverman.